# Are there special/secret moves in Street Hockey 95?

Tags: street-hockey-95

If you don't do anything for awhile, you'll see demo clips of each of the characters and in those, they perform some weird moves that you don't normally see in game (e.g. rocket man doing a front flip + a head butt)

Is this just some demo sprite animation or are there really special moves for them? I've tried a lot of different combinations but I just can't seem to make them do their moves.

Comment: sounds like an .. er.. great.. game.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTltOt3NNVo

Comment: we had fun playing that game when we were young, but we really couldn't make those special moves. i'd still play this in an emulator :P

Comment: Oh man that game was awesome. Now I'm going to pull out my SNES and lose a week of my life :(

Comment: week? that's pretty long man. i usually just finish the tourney in one sitting and i've gotten a whole month's fix already lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested this was just cool animation.  Street Hockey 95 (unfortunately) didn't have any combos to let you do those (SWEET!) moves.